# nix-env -qa not showing latest packages

Tags: nix

I tried to update nix-env but it is not showing latest packages:

```
a_user[~]$ nix-channel --update
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = "en_US",
    LC_COLLATE = "C",
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
downloading Nix expressions from âhttps://nixos.org/releases/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-16.03pre71923.3087ef3//nixexprs.tar.xzâ...
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US",
    LC_ALL = "en_US",
    LC_COLLATE = "C",
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
unpacking channels...
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ nix-env -qa | grep baobab    
baobab-3.16.1
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ nix-env -qa | grep dicom 
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$ nix-env -qa | grep grassroot
a_user[~]$ 
a_user[~]$
```

grassroot-dicom is available: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dicom

Also, baobab version 3.18 is available: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=baobab

Why this discrepancy and how can I resolve this?

Also, how to correct locale settings in Slackware? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your search result for "dicom" found that string in the description of a package, alright, but that package is not called "dicom": it's called `gdcm`. You can do a similar search with `nix-env` as follows:

   ```
   nix-env -qaP --description | grep -i dicom
   gdcm    gdcm-2.4.4    The grassroots cross-platform DICOM implementation
   ```

   The output has three columns. The first one is the attribute path to the package, which you can use to install the package with `nix-env -iA`. The second column shows the package's name, which you can use to install it with `nix-env -i`. The third column is the short description of the package, which has no relevant inside of Nix; it's intended just for humans.

   Now, to install the package, run `nix-env -i gdcm` or `nix-env -iA gdcm`. Both commands will work, but the latter one (the one using the attribute path) is usually faster.
2. The package `baobab-3.18.0` is available in the `master` branch of the Nixpkgs git repository, but it's not yet available in the `nixos-unstable` channel. The channel hasn't advanced to the latest version of `master` yet, because there are regression test failures that need to be fixed before the channel is updated. The new version of `baobab` will show up in the channel in a couple of days (state of 2015-11-26). Simply put, the channel updates every time an entire column in the build set https://hydra.nixos.org/job/nixos/trunk-combined/tested#tabs-constituents is green, and this hasn't happened in a while: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/11097 has more details.